# how to show that $\{x\in \mathbb R^n: f(x)=b\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> (1) Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be a continuous mapping. Let $b\in \mathbb R^m$. Show 
>   $$\{x\in \mathbb R^n: f(x)=b\}$$ 
>   is a closed set.

**My thought**: I want to show that the set contains its limit, but I cannot find its limit. Also, if its limit is $b$, then $b$ is in $\mathbb R^m$ and the set is in $\mathbb R^n$, so how could it be closed? Could someone explain in more detail? Thanks so much.

> (2) Use the result of (1) to show that 
>   $$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: y-x^2=0\}$$ 
>   and 
>   $$\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$$ 
>   are closed and 
>   $$\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n : x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n>0\}$$ 
>   is not closed.

I cannot see the two questions are related. I am confused about how to show $y-x^2=0$ is closed because it seems $y$ could be very large. But why $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n>0$ is not closed? Also I learned in class that ball $B(0,1)$ is not closed. Why is the ball not closed? Why is it different from $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$?

Comment: If $f(x_k) = b$ and $x_k \to x$, then $f(x) = b$.

Comment: What is your definition of open and closed sets?

Answer (score 5):

You should probably know that for all $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\{b\}$ is closed.

Then we can write $$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) =b\} = f^{-1}(\{b\}).$$ Since $f$ is continuous, the conclusion follows. (The inverse image of a closed subset by a continuons fonction is closed)

Answer (score 2):

A subset in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ is closed iff it contains all its limit points, so suppose $\;\{x_n\}\subset K:=\{x\in\Bbb R^n\;;\;f(x)=b\}\;$ converges:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0\implies b=\lim_{n\to\infty}b=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\stackrel{\text{cont.}}=f(x_0)\implies x_0\in K$$